# Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist

Tags: sql-server, freetds

While trying to connect remote SQL Server:

```
$tsql -S localhost -U myuser
```

I got error like:

```
locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
Error 20009 (severity 9):
    Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist
    OS error 61, "Connection refused"
There was a problem connecting to the server
```

The output of `$tsql -C` is as below:

```
Compile-time settings (established with the "configure" script)
                        Version: freetds v0.91
         freetds.conf directory: /usr/local/freetds/conf/freetds
 MS db-lib source compatibility: no
    Sybase binary compatibility: no
                  Thread safety: yes
                  iconv library: no
                    TDS version: 5.0
                          iODBC: no
                       unixodbc: no
          SSPI "trusted" logins: no
                       Kerberos: no
```

I have created tunnel for remote server like:

```
$ssh -L 1433:db_server:1433 user@mid_server
```

This forward the local port 1433 to db_server. I tested. My ssh tunnel works because I can connect to database using Navicat (localhost on 1433). I can telnet localhost on port 1433.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26229487/2083490

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I kinda get it worked by modifying freetds.conf

from

```
[global]
    # TDS protocol version
;   tds version = 4.2
```

to

```
[global]
    # TDS protocol version
tds version = 7.0
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me with ASE 16.0 installed and running on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, both client and server.

- SERVER: Make sure there is an entry in /etc/hosts of your server (sybaseServer). In a standard Ubuntu 14.04  installation you will not find this, but "127.0.1.1 sybaseServer". But sybase seems depends on it.

/etc/hosts
...
192.168.1.100 sybaseServer
...

- CLIENT: The entry in freetds.conf is

[SYBASE]
       host = 192.168.1.100
       port = 5000
       tds version = 5.0

Now you can connect to your server:

$tsql -S SYBASE -U sa

- obviously you have to replace IP-address, servername etc. with your own data