# Error 20009 (severity 9):Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist OS error 111, "Connection refused"

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, odbc, freetds

while trying to connect to remort mssql server by command

```
tsql -S SQLEXPRESS  -U sa
```

passwod :sa
it throws error as 
Error 20009 (severity 9):Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist OS error 111, "Connection refused"

Steps i followed 
    /etc/freetds/freetdsconf.conf

```
[SQLEXPRESS]
host = 192.168.1.9
port = 1433
tds version = 8.0
client charset = UTF-8

/etc/odbcinst.ini
[FreeTDS]
Description     = TDS driver (Sybase/MS SQL)
Driver          =/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup           =/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
CPTimeout       =
CPReuse         =
FileUsage       = 1


etc/odbc.ini
[SQLEXPRESS]
Driver      = FreeTDS
Description = ODBC connection via FreeTDS
Trace       = No
Servername  = 192.168.1.9
Database    = cakephp_results
Port        = 1433
UID         = sa
PWD         = sa
ReadOnly    = No
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26229487/2083490

Answer (score 1):

In your odbc.ini file change 'Servername = ' to 'Server = '. Then remove the UID, PWD and ReadOnly lines from that file temporarily. You may want to remove them altogether and pass in the credentials from your application.

Then, be sure that your MSSQL DB is allowing connections through port 1433, that SQL Server is not blocking the incoming server's IP address, and that you have the correct password.

Also, if that doesn't work, review these [troubleshooting](https://www.freetds.org/userguide/)  instructions: