# PDO Error “Adaptive Server is unavailable” when connecting to MS SQL Database

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm trying to connect to a MSSQL database with odbc in php.
My issue is similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31162553/pdo-error-adaptive-server-is-unavailable-when-connecting-to-ms-sql-database), I can connect with tsql, but not with php.
The answer to the problem not work because I think I don't have SELinux installed (I don't know what it is, but pacman not found this package (or with a similar name) on my computer)
I don't understand why it doesn't work, odbc is installed and detected by php

```
print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers()); 
Array ( [0] => odbc )
```

I'm connecting by doing that:

```
$dsn = 'odbc:Driver=FreeTDS;Server=127.0.0.1;Port:1433;Database=[my base name]';
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
```

My base is not in local, I use a ssh tunel because the base in accessible only at my school, and we need an ssh tunnel. And it work, I can connect myself to the base with tsql.

Answer (score 0):

When I was connecting PHP to our MS SQL server, I could never get a connection established using ODBC drivers.

Instead, I downloaded the official PHP > SQL SERVER drivers direct from Microsoft. You can find them [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098).

Once installed, you must configure your `php.ini` file to include the new drivers, restart your web server and then use the following to open a new connection:

```
$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=SERVER_IP,1433;Database=DATABASE_TO_OPEN;");
```

Comment: Thank you for responding
I don't have ubuntu or red hat, I am running manjaro linux, and microsoft's drivers seems to not exist on arch/manjaro.