# LimeSurvey 250plus build 160206 unable to connect to database

Tags: database-connection, limesurvey

LimeSurvey Installer says:

> Please fix the following input errors:
>
> Connection with database failed. Please check database location, user name and password and try again.

Obviously I changed the password of the user connected to the database to be on the safe side, and checked privileges, but still same problem.

The only thing I see is that the LimeSurvey installer finds `Microsoft SQL Server (dblib)` whereas my host "offers" MySQL databases...

P.S.: Limesurvey worked for years on my site with the same host, it broke a few months ago, but it is only now that I have the time to tackle the issue...

Answer (score 0):

If you want mysql : check if pdo_mysql is enabled in your website.
pdo_dblib is for MSSQL database.
To have a cleanest error (more information) : you can replace this file : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LimeSurvey/LimeSurvey/82fafc14707d310cba9c247b9326ecda7a6a6c96/application/controllers/InstallerController.php

https://github.com/LimeSurvey/LimeSurvey/commit/82fafc14707d310cba9c247b9326ecda7a6a6c96

Comment: pdo_mysql seems to be enabled on the site. did a `php -m` and got: 
PDO
pdo_dblib
pdo_mysql
PDO_ODBC
pdo_pgsql
pdo_sqlite

Comment: I also changed the file `InstallerController.php` as per your suggestion, and when I remove `config.php` (in installation mode) I get a blank page. When `config.php` is present I get: `Internal Server Error

CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection.`

Comment: Update to the last version https://github.com/LimeSurvey/LimeSurvey/commit/c667feb5081cee5134dce8749b10e0ef3c20b5df and apply patch here : https://github.com/LimeSurvey/LimeSurvey/commit/7dcc37ce6cb05283eafc0bde01ea3997db2dacd6

Comment: This time the error is as follows: 

`Please fix the following input errors:

Try again! Connection with database failed.
Reason: SQLSTATE[HY000] Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (severity 9)`

For what it is worth, at `Database type` I still get `Microsoft SQL Server (dblib)`…

Comment: Not a LS issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511369/adaptive-server-is-unavailable-or-does-not-exist-error-connecting-to-sql-serve . YOu're sure for the server : put a phpinfo in place of index.php and validate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Denis, I placed a phpinfo as suggested, and I have various `mysql`, `mysqli` and `mysqlnd` data. I must admit not being very sure what to look for...

Comment: No mysql etc ... pdo. Search for PDO support : and see if yes and what you have. For example, i have mysql, odbc, pgsql, sqlite And do a new installtin (just remove config.php file)