# Python Docker error: [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source (0) (SQLDriverConnect) on SQL Server

Tags: python, docker, containers

I'm trying to make a simple MS SQL Server call from Python by using Docker. The SQL connection is able to establish if I run the **python execute script**, but it **won't work from Docker**.

My code is below

**Dockerfile**

```
from python:3

WORKDIR /code

COPY requirements.txt .


RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install unixodbc -y \
 && apt-get install unixodbc-dev -y \
 && apt-get install freetds-dev -y \
 && apt-get install freetds-bin -y \
 && apt-get install tdsodbc -y \
 && apt-get install --reinstall build-essential -y


RUN echo "[FreeTDS]\n\
Description = FreeTDS Driver\n\
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so\n\
Setup = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so" >> /etc/odbcinst.ini



#Pip command without proxy setting
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY src/ .

CMD ["python", "./producer.py"]
```

**producer.py**

```
import pyodbc



connP = pyodbc.connect('driver={FreeTDS};'
                       'server={MYSERV01\SQLEXPRESS};'
                       'database=ABCD;'                       
                       'uid=****;'
                       'pwd=*****')
```

**requirement.txt**

```
kafka-python
pyodbc==4.0.28
```

**Error message**
[image]

I referred to [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/deploying-python-script-to-docker-container-and-connect-to-external-sql-server-in-10-minutes-225ff4c19ce5) and did. I searched online for resolutions and tried several steps, but nothing helped. I'm pretty new to Docker and no experience in Python, so any help would be really good. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In your `pyodbc.connect` try to give the server as '0.0.0.0' instead of any other value.

If you want to debug it from inside the container, then comment the last `CMD` line of your Dockerfile.

#### Build your Docker container

```
docker build -f Dockerfile -t achu-docker-container .
```

#### Run your Docker Container

```
docker run -it achu-docker-container /bin/bash
```

This will place you inside the container. This is like, ssh to a different machine.

#### Go to your WORKDIR

```
cd code
python ./producer.py
```

What do you get the above above? (If you install any editor using `apt-get install vim` you will be able to interactively edit the `producer.py` file and fix your problem from inside the running container.

Then you can move your changes to your source Dockerfile and build a new image and container with it.

Comment: I did follow the steps and gave this error when ran inside the cmd.
connP = pyodbc.connect('driver={FreeTDS};'
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08S01', '[08S01] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (20009) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Comment: The FreeTDS server is not running inside the container. See if you verify in command line that hte server is running. Ref - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511369/adaptive-server-is-unavailable-or-does-not-exist-error-connecting-to-sql-serve

Comment: Thank you Mr Kumaran - with this link and so many other articles I was able to figure it out. Posted the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to connect to the local SQL Server database. I referred many articles and figured out that the following code works:

the **server** should have `host.docker.inter,<port_no>` -- this was the catch. When it comes to dedicated database where the sql server is different from the docker image, the server name is provided directly, but when both image and database are in same server, the following code works. Please check the port number in the SQL Configuration TCP Address (IP4All)

[image]

Comment: Is it comma or pr colon? Also if you make the server listen to all addresses, then listening to `0.0.0.0` should do too.